# Embed Google Map with branded place markers

Tags: google, google-maps

How do you setup custom place markers when using Google maps that are embedded on your site?

Answer (score 1):

It requires the use of the google maps api.  The custom markers are just images that can be used.  The example there is very elegant by moving to a selected marker based on click.

for a full overview of the google maps api goto:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Marc Grabanski has done an amazing job creating a tutorial to acheive the same effect as above using google maps and Jquery.  There are several Jquery scripts that make working with google maps a little bit easier.  Have a look at:

http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-basics